# LetsEncrypt SSL on private sub domain

Tags: iis, dns, lets-encrypt

We own the `company.com` domain, and have ssl comodo wildcard on it.

We have set up a private dns range `*.intra.company.com` locally on our ADDS Server, unresolvable by the Internet.

I'm wondering whether is possible the install **LetsEncrypt** certificates on **IIS Sites** binded with private domain names, without exposing them to the Internet.
I've seen a 'hack' to register the domainnames pointing to a publicly available IP and then install the certs. In the local network, point the hostname to the real IP's.

Is this the best way?

Comment: Why cannot you use AD Certificate Services? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831740(v%3Dws.11)

Comment: If you just need free trusted certificate for internal use, you could generate certificate with visual studio makecert.https://blog.jayway.com/2014/09/03/creating-self-signed-certificates-with-makecert-exe-for-development/ Or you can just use ADCS.